# Send to Multiple numbers SMS Messaging in Android

Tags: android

how to Send Messaging to Multiple numbers in Android?
Can any body have complete code or demo?
i already had done it for single number, but i can't send it to multiples.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help-how-to-ask
You could at least show us your code, and what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
private void sendMessages(ArrayList<String> addresses, String message) {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    for(String address : addresses) {
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(address, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

It's not group messaging, but each number will receive a text from you :)